# Using Option and None in a spark RDD in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 RDD[Int] sources and noSourcesVertex.
I would like to compute a map that would create 2 new RDD.

```
  val sourcesFormatted = sources.map(x => (Some(x), (Some(x), Some(x))))
  val noSourcesVertexFormatted = noSourcesVertex.map(x => (Some(x), (Some(x), None)))
  val outInit = sourcesFormatted.union(noSourcesVertexFormatted)
```

But when I'm executing the precedent code, I have an error :

> error: type mismatch;  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Some[Int],
>   (Some[Int], None.type))]  required:
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Some[Int], (Some[Int], Some[Int]))]
>            val outInit = sourcesFormatted.union(noSourcesVertexFormatted)

I think this error happens because I'm trying to join 2 RDD whose 3rd column has different type.

I wasn't expecting this behaviour because of what I anderstood of the Option's mecanism, Some(something) and None has the same type -> Option.

Why do I have this error though ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RDDs` are invariant so you have to be specific about the types:

```
val sourcesFormatted: RDD[(Option[Int] (Option[Int], Option[Int]))] = 
  sources.map(x => (Some(x), (Some(x), Some(x))))
val noSourcesVertexFormatted: RDD[(Option[Int] (Option[Int], Option[Int]))] = 
  noSourcesVertex.map(x => (Some(x), (Some(x), None)))
```

or

```
val noSourcesVertexFormatted = 
  noSourcesVertex.map(x => (Some(x), (Some(x), None: Option[Int])))
```

Answer (score 3):

`Some` and `None` are both children of `Option` and not vice versa.

```
Option(something)
```

will return

```
Some(something)
```

But

```
Option(null)
```

will return

```
None
```

Whereas

```
Some(null)
```

will **not** return

```
None
```

`Some` is a `case class` extending `Option` which says that it is not empty and there is a value 
`None` is also a `case class` extending `Option` which says it is empty and trying to get the value should throw `NoSuchElementException`
And
`Option` is an `object` storing a `not null value` as `Some` and `null value` as `None`